# JSX gives no output

Tags: reactjs

Im on Ubuntu 14.04

I installed node

```
sudo apt-get install node
```

I installed npm

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

I installed react-tools

```
sudo npm install -g react-tools
```

When I try:

```
jsx -h
```

I get no output. Any ideas what might be wrong? Likely pebcak but I would appreciate a hint.

Comment: You probably also want `apt-get remove --purge node && apt-get install nodejs` (Google 'node Amateur Packet Radio' for backstory)

Comment: Made a pretty big difference :)

Answer (score 5):

I uninstalled everything and this time I installed the correct nodejs. Thx FakeRainBrigand.

This time I got:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

I solved this with:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```